# fastapi + sqlalchemy + pydantic → how to process many-to-many relations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have `editor`s and `article`s. Many editors may be related to many articles and many articles may have many editors at same time.

My DB tables are

- **Article**

| id | subject | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Year Holidays | In this year... etc etc etc |

- **Editor**

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | some@email |

- **EditorArticleRelation**

| editor_id | article_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

My models are

```py
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base

class Editor(Base):
    __tablename__ = "editor"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(32), unique=False, index=False, nullable=True)
    email = Column(String(115), unique=True, index=True)
    articles = relationship("Article",
                    secondary=EditorArticleRelation,
                    back_populates="articles",
                    cascade="all, delete")

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = "article"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    subject = Column(String(32), unique=True, index=False)
    text = Column(String(256), unique=True, index=True, nullable=True)
    editors = relationship("Editor",
                    secondary=EditorArticleRelation,
                    back_populates="editors",
                    cascade="all, delete")

EditorArticleRelation = Table('editorarticlerelation', Base.metadata,
    Column('editor_id', Integer, ForeignKey('editor.id')),
    Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
)
```

My schemas are

```py
from typing import Optional, List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class EditorBase(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    email: str

class EditorCreate(EditorBase):
    pass

class Editor(EditorBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    subject: str
    text: str

class ArticleCreate(ArticleBase):
    # WHAT I NEED TO SET HERE???
    editor_ids: List[int] = []

class Article(ArticleBase):
    id: int
    editors: List[Editor] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

My crud

```py
def create_article(db: Session, article_data: schema.ArticleCreate):
    db_article = model.Article(subject=article_data.subject, text=article_data.text, ??? HOW TO SET EDITORS HERE ???)
    db.add(db_article)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_article)
    return db_article
```

My route

```py
@app.post("/articles/", response_model=schema.Article)
def create_article(article_data: schema.ArticleCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_article = crud.get_article_by_name(db, name=article_data.name)
    if db_article:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="article already registered")
    if len(getattr(article_data, 'editor_ids', [])) > 0:
        ??? WHAT I NEED TO SET HERE???
    return crud.create_article(db=db, article_data=article_data)
```

#### What I want →

I want to post data for article creation API and automatically resolve and add editor relations, or raise error if some of editors doesn't exist:

```json
{
  "subject": "Fresh news"
  "text": "Today is ..."
  "editor_ids": [1, 2, ...]
}
```

#### Questions are:

1. How to correctly set crud operations (`HOW TO SET EDITORS HERE` place)?
2. How to correctly set create/read schemas and relation fields (especially `WHAT I NEED TO SET HERE` place)?
3. How to correctly set route code (especially `WHAT I NEED TO SET HERE` place)?
4. If here is no possible to resolve relations automatically, what place will be better to resolve relations (check if editor exists, etc)? route or crud?
5. Maybe my way is bad at all? If you know any examples how to handle many-to-many relations with `pydantic` and `sqlalchemy`, any information will be welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if my solution is most effective, but I did it by this way:

- route (same as in question):

```py
...
@app.post("/articles/", response_model=schema.Article)
def create_article(article_data: schema.ArticleCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_article = crud.get_article_by_name(db, name=article_data.name)
    if db_article:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="article already registered")
    return crud.create_article(db=db, article_data=article_data)
...
```

- schema (same as in question):

```py
...
class ArticleCreate(ArticleBase):
    editor_ids: List[int] = []
...
```

- crud (**solution is here**):

```py
def create_article(db: Session, article_data: schema.ArticleCreate):
    db_article = model.Article(subject=article_data.subject, text=article_data.text)
    if (editors := db.query(model.Editor).filter(model.Editor.id.in_(article_data.editor_ids))).count() == len(endpoint_data.topic_ids):
        db_article.topics.extend(editors)
    else:
        # even if at least one editor is not found, an error is raised
        # if existence is not matter you can skip this check and add relations only for existing data
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="editor not found")
    db.add(db_article)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_article)
    return db_article
```

Any better ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2):

A solution I found.

```
def create_user_groups(db: Session, user_groups: schemas.UserGroupsBase):
    db_user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_groups.id_user).first()
    db_group = db.query(models.Group).filter(models.Group.id == user_groups.id_group).first()

    if not db_user and db_group:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="User or Group not found in system.")

    db_user.groups.append(db_group)

    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than the existing answer from the author of the OP. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29944930)

Comment: @Brayan Your answer is mostly repeating `create_article` method in my own answer.